# Proguard app crash (Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Lcom/facebook/jni/HybridData)

Tags: react-native, proguard

I am getting a fatal exception when i use proguard on my release build.

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Lcom/facebook/jni/HybridData;" field "mHybridData" in class "Lcom/facebook/react/cxxbridge/CatalystInstanceImpl;" or its superclasses`

Here is the stacktrace:

```
03-17 07:06:58.852  1057  1432 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.myApp.staging/com.myApp.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10008 on display 0
03-17 07:06:58.867  1057  1451 I ActivityManager: Start proc 2234:com.myApp.staging/u0a62 for activity com.myApp.staging/com.myApp.MainActivity
03-17 07:06:58.892  2234  2234 D FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
03-17 07:06:58.894  2234  2234 W InstanceID/Rpc: Failed to resolve REGISTER intent, falling back
03-17 07:06:58.895  2234  2234 W InstanceID/Rpc: Both Google Play Services and legacy GSF package are missing
03-17 07:06:58.896  2234  2234 W GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
03-17 07:06:58.896  2234  2234 I DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:2 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:0
03-17 07:06:58.896  2234  2234 I DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
03-17 07:06:58.897  2234  2234 W DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
03-17 07:06:58.897  2234  2234 W GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
03-17 07:06:58.897  2234  2234 I DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.crash:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.crash:0
03-17 07:06:58.897  2234  2234 E FirebaseCrash: Failed to initialize crash reporting: com.google.android.gms.d.bk$a: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
03-17 07:06:58.897  2234  2234 D FirebaseCrash: Cannot register Firebase Analytics listener since Firebase Crash Reporting is not enabled
03-17 07:06:58.902  2234  2234 I FA      : App measurement is starting up, version: 9877
03-17 07:06:58.902  2234  2234 I FA      : To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
03-17 07:06:58.905  2234  2234 I FA      : To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
03-17 07:06:58.905  2234  2234 I FA      :   adb shell setprop firebase.analytics.debug-mode com.myApp.staging
03-17 07:06:58.908  2234  2234 I FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
03-17 07:06:58.920  2234  2234 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.myApp.staging/lib-main
03-17 07:06:58.921  2234  2234 I fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.myApp.staging/lib-main
03-17 07:06:58.921  2234  2234 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.myApp.staging/lib-main
03-17 07:06:58.941  2234  2234 D ReactNative: [CodePush] Loading JS bundle from "assets://index.android.bundle"
03-17 07:06:58.957  2234  2234 I art     : Thread[1,tid=2234,Native,Thread*=0xf3e34a00,peer=0x73a04258,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.myApp.staging-1/lib/x86/libfb.so"
03-17 07:06:58.967  2234  2262 D OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-17 07:06:58.977  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupViewManager
03-17 07:06:58.982  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.a
03-17 07:06:58.987  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeViewManager
03-17 07:06:58.987  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.b
03-17 07:06:58.993  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextViewManager
03-17 07:06:58.996  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.e
03-17 07:06:58.998  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewManager
03-17 07:06:59.000  2234  2234 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xed716b90, tid 2234
03-17 07:06:59.000  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.d
03-17 07:06:59.003  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDialogPickerManager
03-17 07:06:59.004  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.uimanager.g
03-17 07:06:59.004  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager
03-17 07:06:59.005  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDropdownPickerManager
03-17 07:06:59.005  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollViewManager
03-17 07:06:59.006  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageManager
03-17 07:06:59.007  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ReactModalHostManager
03-17 07:06:59.009  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.b
03-17 07:06:59.009  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager
03-17 07:06:59.010  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.b
03-17 07:06:59.010  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextManager
03-17 07:06:59.012  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.g
03-17 07:06:59.013  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollViewManager
03-17 07:06:59.013  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager
03-17 07:06:59.014  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager$a
03-17 07:06:59.014  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager
03-17 07:06:59.016  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager$a
03-17 07:06:59.016  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageViewManager
03-17 07:06:59.017  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.a
03-17 07:06:59.018  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputManager
03-17 07:06:59.020  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.j
03-17 07:06:59.022  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager
03-17 07:06:59.023  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.toolbar.ReactToolbarManager
03-17 07:06:59.024  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager
03-17 07:06:59.026  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.viewpager.ReactViewPagerManager
03-17 07:06:59.026  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextViewManager
03-17 07:06:59.026  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.webview.ReactWebViewManager
03-17 07:06:59.027  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.swiperefresh.SwipeRefreshLayoutManager
03-17 07:06:59.031  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.reactnative.photoview.PhotoViewManager
03-17 07:06:59.032  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.react.rnspinkit.RNSpinkit
03-17 07:06:59.033  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBLikeViewManager
03-17 07:06:59.035  1452  1571 E Surface : getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xe8e02d90
03-17 07:06:59.036  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBLoginButtonManager
03-17 07:06:59.036  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSendButtonManager
03-17 07:06:59.037  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBShareButtonManager
03-17 07:06:59.037  2234  2261 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.oney.WebRTCModule.RTCVideoViewManager
03-17 07:06:59.053  2234  2262 D libEGL  : loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
03-17 07:06:59.054  2234  2262 D libEGL  : loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
03-17 07:06:59.054  2234  2261 D JVM     : JVM::Initialize@[tid=2261]
03-17 07:06:59.054  2234  2261 D JVM     : JVM::JVM@[tid=2261]
03-17 07:06:59.061  2234  2261 W AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma
03-17 07:06:59.062  2234  2261 W AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/vnd.rn-realaudio
03-17 07:06:59.064  2234  2262 D libEGL  : loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
03-17 07:06:59.064  2234  2261 W AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
03-17 07:06:59.064  2234  2261 W AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/ac3
03-17 07:06:59.065  2234  2261 W AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ape
03-17 07:06:59.066  2234  2261 W AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/vnd.dts
03-17 07:06:59.067  2234  2261 W AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-pcm
03-17 07:06:59.067  2234  2261 W AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/ffmpeg
03-17 07:06:59.068  2234  2262 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xeebd2920, tid 2262
03-17 07:06:59.069  2234  2261 W VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
03-17 07:06:59.070  2234  2261 W VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/vnd.rn-realvideo
03-17 07:06:59.071  2234  2261 W VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/vc1
03-17 07:06:59.071  2234  2261 W VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-flv
03-17 07:06:59.072  2234  2261 W VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
03-17 07:06:59.072  2234  2261 W VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/ffmpeg
03-17 07:06:59.076  2234  2262 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-17 07:06:59.082  2234  2261 I VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
03-17 07:06:59.083  2234  2261 I org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Trying to find HW decoder for mime video/x-vnd.on2.vp8
03-17 07:06:59.083  2234  2261 I org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Found candidate decoder OMX.google.vp8.decoder
03-17 07:06:59.083  2234  2261 I org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: No HW decoder found for mime video/x-vnd.on2.vp8
03-17 07:06:59.083  2234  2261 I org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Trying to find HW decoder for mime video/x-vnd.on2.vp9
03-17 07:06:59.083  2234  2261 I org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Found candidate decoder OMX.google.vp9.decoder
03-17 07:06:59.083  2234  2261 I org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: No HW decoder found for mime video/x-vnd.on2.vp9
03-17 07:06:59.083  2234  2261 I org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Trying to find HW decoder for mime video/avc
03-17 07:06:59.083  2234  2261 I org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Found candidate decoder OMX.ffmpeg.h264.decoder
03-17 07:06:59.083  2234  2261 I org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: No HW decoder found for mime video/avc
03-17 07:06:59.085  2234  2266 D JVM     : AttachCurrentThreadIfNeeded::ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.085  2234  2266 D JVM     : Attaching thread to JVM
03-17 07:06:59.086  2234  2266 D JVM     : JVM::environment@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.086  2234  2266 D JVM     : JNIEnvironment::ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.086  2234  2266 D AudioManager: ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.086  2234  2266 D JVM     : JNIEnvironment::RegisterNatives(org/webrtc/voiceengine/WebRtcAudioManager)
03-17 07:06:59.086  2234  2266 D JVM     : NativeRegistration::ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.086  2234  2266 D JVM     : NativeRegistration::NewObject@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.086  2234  2266 I org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager: ctor@[name=Thread-167, id=167]
03-17 07:06:59.087  2234  2266 I org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager: Sample rate is set to 44100 Hz
03-17 07:06:59.091  2234  2266 I org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioEffects: canUseAcousticEchoCanceler: false
03-17 07:06:59.091  2234  2266 I org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioEffects: canUseAutomaticGainControl: false
03-17 07:06:59.091  2234  2266 I org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioEffects: canUseNoiseSuppressor: false
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D AudioManager: OnCacheAudioParameters@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D AudioManager: hardware_aec: 0
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D AudioManager: hardware_agc: 0
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D AudioManager: hardware_ns: 0
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D AudioManager: low_latency_output: 0
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D AudioManager: pro_audio: 0
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D AudioManager: sample_rate: 44100
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D AudioManager: channels: 1
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D AudioManager: output_buffer_size: 3174
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D AudioManager: input_buffer_size: 2048
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D JVM     : GlobalRef::ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D AudioManager: JavaAudioManager::ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D AudioManager: IsLowLatencyPlayoutSupported()
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D JVM     : AttachCurrentThreadIfNeeded::ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D JVM     : JVM::environment@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D JVM     : JNIEnvironment::ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D AudioTrackJni: ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D JVM     : JNIEnvironment::RegisterNatives(org/webrtc/voiceengine/WebRtcAudioTrack)
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D JVM     : NativeRegistration::ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D JVM     : NativeRegistration::NewObject@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 I org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: ctor@[name=Thread-167, id=167]
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D JVM     : GlobalRef::ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D JVM     : AttachCurrentThreadIfNeeded::ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D JVM     : JVM::environment@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D JVM     : JNIEnvironment::ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D AudioRecordJni: ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D JVM     : JNIEnvironment::RegisterNatives(org/webrtc/voiceengine/WebRtcAudioRecord)
03-17 07:06:59.093  2234  2266 D JVM     : NativeRegistration::ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.094  2234  2266 D JVM     : NativeRegistration::NewObject@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.094  2234  2266 I org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioRecord: ctor@[name=Thread-167, id=167]
03-17 07:06:59.094  2234  2266 I org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioEffects: ctor@[name=Thread-167, id=167]
03-17 07:06:59.094  2234  2266 D JVM     : GlobalRef::ctor@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.094  2234  2266 D AudioManager: SetActiveAudioLayer(5)@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.094  2234  2266 D AudioManager: delay_estimate_in_milliseconds: 150
03-17 07:06:59.094  2234  2266 D AudioTrackJni: AttachAudioBuffer@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.094  2234  2266 D AudioTrackJni: SetPlayoutSampleRate(44100)
03-17 07:06:59.094  2234  2266 D AudioTrackJni: SetPlayoutChannels(1)
03-17 07:06:59.094  2234  2266 D AudioRecordJni: AttachAudioBuffer
03-17 07:06:59.094  2234  2266 D AudioRecordJni: SetRecordingSampleRate(44100)
03-17 07:06:59.094  2234  2266 D AudioRecordJni: SetRecordingChannels(1)
03-17 07:06:59.094  2234  2266 D AudioRecordJni: total_delay_in_milliseconds: 150
03-17 07:06:59.094  2234  2266 D AudioManager: Init@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.094  2234  2266 I org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager: init@[name=Thread-167, id=167]
03-17 07:06:59.095  2234  2266 I org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager: audio mode is: MODE_NORMAL
03-17 07:06:59.096  2234  2266 D AudioTrackJni: Init@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.096  2234  2266 D AudioRecordJni: Init@[tid=2266]
03-17 07:06:59.102  2234  2265 I org.webrtc.Logging: PeerConnectionFactory: onNetworkThreadReady
03-17 07:06:59.103  2234  2266 I org.webrtc.Logging: PeerConnectionFactory: onWorkerThreadReady
03-17 07:06:59.105  2234  2267 I org.webrtc.Logging: PeerConnectionFactory: onSignalingThreadReady
03-17 07:06:59.106  2234  2261 D InCallManager: fallback to old school screen locker...
03-17 07:06:59.107  2234  2261 D InCallManager: InCallManager initialized
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myApp.staging, PID: 2234
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Lcom/facebook/jni/HybridData;" field "mHybridData" in class "Lcom/facebook/react/cxxbridge/CatalystInstanceImpl;" or its superclasses
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.initializeBridge(Native Method)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$b.a(Unknown Source)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.j.a(Unknown Source)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.j.a(Unknown Source)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.j$a.a(Unknown Source)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.j$a.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-17 07:06:59.110  2234  2261 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 3 more
03-17 07:06:59.110  1057  1451 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.myApp.staging/com.myApp.MainActivity
03-17 07:06:59.126  2234  2262 W EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-17 07:06:59.126  2234  2262 W OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xeebd3e00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-17 07:06:59.129  1057  1451 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe8d86a80, tid 1451
03-17 07:06:59.145  2234  2249 I FA      : This instance being marked as an uploader
03-17 07:06:59.150  1080  1080 E EGL_emulation: tid 1080: eglCreateSyncKHR(1215): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
03-17 07:06:59.191    98    98 D         : Socket deconnection
03-17 07:06:59.235  1057  2223 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-17 07:06:59.250  1057  2223 W EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-17 07:06:59.250  1057  2223 W OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xdc561b20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-17 07:06:59.269  1452  1571 W EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-17 07:06:59.269  1452  1571 W OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xdf71e5a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-17 07:06:59.271  2234  2262 E Surface : getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xe8e024d0
03-17 07:06:59.299  1057  1474 W ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.service.START pkg=com.google.android.gms } U=0: not found
03-17 07:06:59.353   751  1132 W AudioFlinger: write blocked for 488 msecs, 3 delayed writes, thread 0xf1e80000
03-17 07:06:59.377  1057  1483 I ActivityManager: Killing 1886:com.android.email/u0a34 (adj 15): empty #17
03-17 07:07:00.601  2234  2261 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 2234 SIG: 9
03-17 07:07:00.606  1057  1451 D GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 4
03-17 07:07:00.629  1057  1483 I ActivityManager: Process com.myApp.staging (pid 2234) has died
03-17 07:07:00.632  1057  2223 E Surface : getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xdf4db920
03-17 07:07:00.637  1057  2223 D OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xdee4b280 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xdc5609a0
03-17 07:07:00.639  1057  1432 W InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2234 uid 10062
03-17 07:07:00.818  1057  1076 W AppOps  : Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
03-17 07:07:01.194    98    98 D         : Socket deconnection
```

- React Native version: 0.42.0

Proguard file is:

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.3/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Disabling obfuscation is useful if you collect stack traces from production crashes
# (unless you are using a system that supports de-obfuscate the stack traces).
#-dontobfuscate

# React Native

# Keep our interfaces so they can be used by other ProGuard rules.
# See http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/466/
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.proguard.annotations.KeepGettersAndSetters
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip

# Do not strip any method/class that is annotated with @DoNotStrip
-keep @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip class *
-keep @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip class *
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip *;
    @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip *;
}

-keepclassmembers @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.KeepGettersAndSetters class * {
  void set*(***);
  *** get*();
}

-keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule { *; }
-keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule { *; }
-keepclassmembers,includedescriptorclasses class * { native <methods>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIProp <fields>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp <methods>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactPropGroup <methods>; }

-dontwarn com.facebook.react.**

# okhttp

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**

# okio

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn okio.**

# fixed on 0.43.0 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/12511
-dontwarn com.facebook.fbui.textlayoutbuilder.proxy.StaticLayoutProxy

# The rxjava library depends on sun.misc.Unsafe, which is unavailable on Android
# The rxjava team is aware of this, and mention in the docs that they only use
# the unsafe functionality if the platform supports it.
#  - https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/1415#issuecomment-48390883
#  - https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/internal/util/unsafe/UnsafeAccess.java#L23
-dontwarn rx.internal.util.**

# Webrtc
-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

had to add this:

```
-keep class com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.ModuleRegistryHolder { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaScriptExecutor { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.bridge.ExecutorToken { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableType { *; }
```

Answer (score 9):

I had a related error, but slightly different with React Native 0.47.1:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Lcom/facebook/jni/HybridData;" field "mHybridData" in class "Lcom/facebook/react/bridge/JavaScriptExecutor;" or its superclasses
                                                       at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.initializeBridge(Native Method)
                                                       at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.<init>(SourceFile:114)
                                                       at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.<init>(SourceFile:42)
                                                       at bnv.a(SourceFile:574)
                                                       at bmg.a(SourceFile:999)
                                                       at bmg.a(SourceFile:109)
                                                       at bmg$4.run(SourceFile:802)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I had to add slightly different lines to my Proguard file to fix:

```
-keep class com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptExecutor { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableType { *; }
```

It seems the root cause for this is when you integrate React Native into an existing Android project, the Proguard rules might not include `-dontobfuscate` which the default React Native Proguard file has. I'm going to update this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12994) so hopefully a fix is put into a future version of RN.

Comment: This worked for me. My case was also integrating RN with a native app

Answer (score 0):

For errors like NoSuchmethod,FieldError,ClassNotFound,MethodNotFound

Under progurad-rules.pro

Add your class

-keep class com.exampleApp.yourClass {*;}